# AJAX - submit multiple POST data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am desperately trying to submit multiple POST variables via AJAX, but just cant get manage to get the formatting right... Problem is that I have both a hardcoded / written `action=problem_lookup` variable and a dynamic field input as `$(this).val` and just cant manage to get both into one data string...

this works well:

```
data: 'problem=' + $(this).val(),
```

This does not:

```
data: { action: 'problem_lookup' , problem: $("problem").val() },
data: { action: 'problem_lookup' , problem: $(this).val() },
data: { action: problem_lookup, problem: $(this).val() },
```

I tried numerous formats from other threads and looked at the official jquery manual, but cant seem to get this figured out. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

full script below, tried the solutions posted so far but no success. `$("problem")` is a `<select>` field (with Select2 running) hence shouldnt cause me so much frustration, especially since the original approach with `data: 'problem=' + $(this).val(),` works fine.

```
$(function () {
    $('#problem').change(function () {                      // on change in field "problem"

    var data = {
        action: 'problem_lookup', 
        problem: $("problem").val()
    }

        $.ajax({                                            // launch AJAX connection
            type: 'POST',                                   // via protocol POST
            url: 'ajax.php',
            //data: 'problem=' + $(this).val(),             // send $_POST string
            //data:"{'action':'"+action+"','problem':'"+$(this).val()+"'}",
            //data:"{'action':'problem_lookup','problem':'"+$(this).val()+"'}",
            //data: { action: 'problem_lookup' , problem: $("problem").val() },
            //data : data_string,
            data: $.param(data),
            dataType: 'json',                               // encode with JSON
            success: function (data)
            {
                // do something
            },
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: If you want to pass multiple value in `data`, then pass it as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue is in the

```
          $("problem")
```

Jquery call.

If.problem is a css class  try  with

```
          $(".problem")
```

if problem is a css id try with

```
       $("#problem")
```

For posting arrays of object you can build data as an object containing arrays, changing a little bit your structure. Something like this

```
 Var obj={};
 obj.postData=[];
 obj.postData.push(/*your first object here*/);
 ...
 obj.postData.push(/*your n-th object here*/);


    $.ajax({    
         .....
        data:obj;
        ......
     });
```

Comment: its a select field with an `id`, hence tried the `$("#problem")` approach but also no result...

Comment: ironically, the `#problem` was the problem... switched it to an array submission and things suddenly worked. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try the *FormData()* [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('action', value);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your data variable first like this:

```
var data = {
    action: 'problem_lookup', 
    problem: $("problem").val()
}
```

In **AJAX** serialize your data using [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/),

```
data: $.param(data),
```

---

**Note:** Twice check if `$("problem").val()` is correct. If `problem` is a class, you need to specify like this `$(".problem").val()` or if it is ID, `$("#problem").val()`

Comment: did all that, but no cigar. `#problem` is an ID, I checked the syntax and its correct, still, I dont get any result back...